# Use an 'apply' function to perform code with conditional statements in R

Tags: r, if-statement, lapply

I have been working on a project for which I need to find peaks and valleys in a dataset (not just the highest numbers per column, but all of the peaks and valleys). 
I did manage to get it to work on 1 column, but I use a for-loop for that and I need to do this for about 50 columns, so I think I should use an 'apply' function. I just don't know how to do so. Can I put 'if' statements and such in an 'apply' function?

Here is what I used for checking one column:
('First' is the name of the dataset and 'Seq1' is the first column)

```
Lowest = 0
Highest = 0
Summits = vector('numeric')
Valleys = vector('numeric')

for (i in 1:length(First$Seq1))
{
    if (!is.na(First$Seq1[i+1]))
    {
        if (First$Seq1[i] < Lowest) {Lowest = First$Seq1[i]}
        if (First$Seq1[i] > Highest) {Highest = First$Seq1[i]}  

        if (First$Seq1[i] > 0 && First$Seq1[i+1] < 0) 
        { Summits <- append(Summits, Highest, after=length(Summits)) }
        if (First$Seq1[i] < 0 && First$Seq1[i+1] > 0) 
        { Valleys <- append(Valleys, Lowest, after=length(Summits)) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can! I would first define a helper function that defines what is to be done with one specific column and then you call that function within apply:

```
    HelperFun <- function(x) {
    # your code from above, replacing 'Seq1' by x
    }
    apply(First, 2, HelperFun)
```

Comment: I have a question about the x. What exactly happens to it? Is it increased by 1 every time? Because if I replace Seq1 with x, I get the error that the x doesn't exist.

Comment: I now have it running! Thanks! The only thing I have to figure out now is what's the best way to store the results. 

I had to add 'function(x) ' before 'HelperFun' by the way. Should anyone else want to know.

Comment: You shouldn't need to "add 'function(x) ' before 'HelperFun'". So you probably did not fully understand how `apply` works since you did something that shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

An `*apply` function is not better for this than a `for` loop, provided you don't grow an object in the `for` loop. You must never use `append` in a loop. Pre-allocate your results object and fill it.

This finds all local minima on a grid:

```
#an example
set.seed(42)
plane <- matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 5), 10)

#plot
library(raster)
plot(raster(plane))

#initialize a logical matrix
res <- matrix(TRUE, ncol = ncol(plane), nrow = nrow(plane))

#check for each subgrid of 2 times 2 cells which of the cells is the minimum
for (i in 1:(nrow(plane) - 1)) {
  for (j in 1:(ncol(plane) - 1)) {
    inds <- as.matrix(expand.grid(r = i + 0:1, c = j + 0:1))
    #cell must be a minimum of all 4 subgrids it is part of
    res[inds] <- res[inds] & plane[inds] == min(plane[inds])
  }
}

print(res)
plane[res]
#[1] -13.282277  -8.906542  -8.585043 -12.071038  -3.919195 -14.965450  -5.215595  -5.498904  -5.971644  -2.380870  -7.296070

#highlight local minima
plot(rasterToPolygons(raster(res)), border = t(res), add = TRUE)

library(reshape2)
res1 <- melt(res)
res1 <- res1[res1$value,]
text(x = res1$Var2 /10 - 0.05, 
     y = 1-res1$Var1 /10 + 0.05, 
     labels = round(plane[res],1))
```

[image: resulting plot]

I've assumed here that diagonal neighbors are counted as neighbors and not only neighbors in the same column or row. But this would be trivial to change.

Comment: Problem with defining the output before the loop is that I have no idea how long the output will be. It can be anything from 0 up to a quite high value. I could set the length to 1000, since I will never get that many, but then I will often have most of the array empty. I probably have to shorten the arrays afterwards or something...?

Comment: Sure. My suggestion is to return a logical matrix (see my code) which for each value indicates if it is a local minimum. You can then use this to subset your input matrix if you are interested in the values themselves.

Comment: My dataset is actually quite different from the one you were showing here. I have analyzed 54 individual videos for the darkness within a certain area. I am looking at dark waves going over a flock of birds. That is why I'm looking for light and dark peaks. I am never sure how far apart (in time) these waves will be, and I can thus not see how far away I have to look for a maximum or minimum. That differs per video.

Comment: So change the content of the `for` loop to `inds <- i + 0:1; res[inds] <- res[inds] & plane[inds] == min(plane[inds])`? I'm not quite sure why you compare with 0 in your example. But as I said: Pre-allocate your result object. You can then use `apply` of course, but please don't use `append`. Growing an object in a loop is extremely slow.

Comment: The data are normalised to swing around 0, so if I check whether or not the data go from positive to negative, I know I have to search for a peak before that point (and after the previous intersection with the x-axis)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not the solution you want --- you have one-dimensional time series, but here is a (more direct) variation on Roland's solution.

```
#example data
set.seed(42)
plane <- matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 5), 10)
library(raster)
r <- raster(plane)

f <- focal(r, matrix(1,3,3), min, pad=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE) 
x <- r == f
mins <- mask(r, x, maskvalue=FALSE)

pts <- rasterToPoints(mins)
cells <- cellFromXY(x, pts)

r[cells]

plot(r)
text(mins, digits=1)
plot(rasterToPolygons(mins), add=TRUE)
```